# Free oscillations and natural frequencies question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given a mass-and-spring system with a couple second-order differential equations describing the behavior of the system. Those are:

$$x^{\prime \prime} +50x - \frac{25}{2}y = 0$$ and $$y^{\prime \prime} + 50y -50x = 0$$

We set up an operational determinant and calculate the general solutions as follows, as well as make sure we have four independent arbitrary constants

$$x(t) = a_1 \cos (5t) + a_2 \sin (5t) + a_3 \cos (5t \sqrt{3}) + a_4 \sin (5t \sqrt {3})$$ $$y(t) = 2a_1 \cos (5t) + 2a_2 \sin (5t) - 2a_3 \cos (5t \sqrt{3}) - 2a_4 \sin (5t \sqrt {3})$$

Using a bit of trigonometry, we can rewrite the equations a bit in terms of two particular solutions $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ of the system for

$$x_1 (t) = a_1 \cos (5t) + a_2 \sin (5t) = A \cos(5t - \alpha)$$
$$y_1 (t) = 2a_1 \cos (5t) + 2a_2 \sin (5t) = 2A \cos(5t - \alpha)$$
and 
$$x_2 (t) = a_3 \cos (5t \sqrt{3}) + a_4 \sin (5t \sqrt {3}) = B \cos(5t\sqrt{3} - \beta)$$
$$y_2 (t) = -2a_3 \cos (5t \sqrt{3}) - 2a_4 \sin (5t \sqrt {3}) = -2B \cos(5t\sqrt{3} - \beta)$$

Here are my questions (I need a really intuitive answer because I don't really understand this):

**#1. How do we know that those two solutions, $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, are actually solutions? More specifically, what is the significance about *these* solutions? Obviously we can reach the solutions when we set $a_3$ and $a_4$ to zero and then do the same with $a_1$ and $a_2$... but what's the intuition behind this?**

**#2. The book describes these two solutions as natural modes of oscillation that exhibit two natural frequencies. What are natural modes of oscillation and how do I find the natural frequencies? Could someone give me a physical description of this answer? **

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1a)** You can check that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are solutions by substituting them in the system of ODEs, as they should *solve* the system, i.e. they should obey the equations.

**1b) and 2**. Your solutions are linear combinations of the functions $\cos(5t)$, $\sin(5t)$, $\cos(5\sqrt{3}\,t)$ and $\sin(5\sqrt{3}\,t)$. Note that these functions are of the form $\cos/\sin(\alpha\,t)$, with $\alpha = 5$ or $\alpha = 5 \sqrt{3}$. The function $\cos(\alpha t)$ describes an oscillation with period $\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}$, i.e. with frequency $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave). The same holds for $\sin(\alpha t)$. Therefore, you see that the general solution to the system of ODEs combines oscillations with two separate frequencies, $\frac{5}{2\pi}$ and $\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}$. By choosing either $a_{1,2}=0$ or $a_{3,4}=0$, you can find two solutions, with $(x_1,y_1)$ *only* exhibiting oscillations with frequency $\frac{5}{2\pi}$, and $(x_2,y_2)$ *only* exhibiting oscillations with frequency $\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}$.

Now, you can see that the general solution $(x,y)$ is a **superposition** (i.e. a linear combination) of these two solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: The answer in the book reads "In the natural mode with frequency $\omega_1 = 5$ the masses move in the same direction, while in the natural mode with frequency $\omega_2 = 5\sqrt{3}$ they move in opposite directions. In each case the amplitude of the motion $m_2$ is twice that of $m_1$." How do we know this? How do I find the frequencies, and from there how can I determine the amplitude and the direction of the movement?

Comment: And what is the natural oscillation?

Comment: These questions consider the physical interpretation of the solutions you found. I very, very strongly suggest you read the Wikipedia lemma I linked in my answer.

Comment: I had only read a small part regarding the frequency, but I will go back and read it in its entirety! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't hesitate to ask if some things remain unclear.